# Can I easily remount an external USB drive without unplugging it?

Tags: usb, automounting

Sometimes, a USB drive (or equivalent) that I have plugged in to my machine gets unmounted.  Now, I know I could unplug it and plug it back in to remount it, but is it possible to **easily** do it from within the system?

For me, "easily" means "without using sudo" and without having to set up any special files, permissions, groups, or directories.  It happens infrequently enough that things like that would be overkill.  But somehow having to unplug and replug the drive in seems ... not quite right, somehow.

I'm using Debian Squeeze with Gnome, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but Nautilus will give you what you want.

Comment: @Tshepang: The device disappears from Nautilus completely.  It's as if it has been unplugged, except that it hasn't.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at **`gnome-disk-utility`**. I provides a tool named `palimpsest` which allows you to see all storage devices.

Here's what mine looks like:

[image]

Comment: That looks very useful.  I didn't know that that existed (just tracked it down through the menus).  I'll take a look and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Is there any way to accomplish the same thing as this "Mount volume" from the command line, without opening this utility?

Comment: @jrdioko there ought to be; I suggested this as it's damn easy to use, without the need to read a manual

Comment: Coming back to this after a bit ... I just had occasion to try this over an `ssh -X` connection (so I couldn't physically remove and re-insert the drive) and whilst it could see the drive, clicking on `Mount volume` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at `pmount` this is a special version of mount for USB devices :)

Comment: Cool utility, however it doesn't re-mount exactly the same as it would by unplugging and replugging (in my case, `(rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks)` vs. `(rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,errors=remount-ro)`)